# GetWritabledatabase null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

Why can't I access the `getwritabledatabase` in `public void onActivityResult` where it keeps on saying can't resolve `getWritabledatabase`. Here I edit the code and I declare `dbhelper` as global but I am still getting the error:

//here is the logcat

> Exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()' on a
>   null object reference

Here is my code:

```
public class AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnimport;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    public static final int requestcode = 1;

    CountriesDbAdapter dbHelper = new CountriesDbAdapter(this);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = new CountriesDbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        //Clean all data
        dbHelper.deleteAllCountries();

        //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
        displayListView();
        btnimport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupload);
        btnimport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this);
                alertdialog.setTitle("Confirm Import...");
                alertdialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Import Data?");
                alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        fileintent.setType("gagt/sdf");
                        try {
                            startActivityForResult(fileintent, requestcode);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                           //empty
                        }
                    }
                });

                alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Import Canceled" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }
                });
                alertdialog.show();
            }
        });

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data == null)
            return;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case requestcode:
                String filepath = data.getData().getPath();
                 dbHelper = new CountriesDbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db =  dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                String tableName = "Countsheet";
                db.execSQL("delete from " + tableName);
                try {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            FileReader file = new FileReader(filepath);
                            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
                            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                            String line = "";
                            db.beginTransaction();

                            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                                String[] str = line.split(",", 5);  // defining 5 columns with null or blank field //values acceptance
                                //Id, category,code,Description,Unit,Quantity
                                String company = str[0].toString();
                                String Name = str[1].toString();
                                String Price = str[2].toString();
                                String units = str[3].toString();
                                String quants = str[4].toString();


                                contentValues.put("Category", company);
                                contentValues.put("Code", Name);
                                contentValues.put("Description", Price);
                                contentValues.put("Unit", units);
                                contentValues.put("Quantity", quants);
                                db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
                                //                                lbl.setText("Successfully Updated Database.");
                            }
                            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                            db.endTransaction();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            if (db.inTransaction())
                                db.endTransaction();
                            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                            d.setTitle(e.getMessage().toString() + "first");
                            d.show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (db.inTransaction())
                            db.endTransaction();
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Only CSV files allowed");
                        d.show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    if (db.inTransaction())
                        db.endTransaction();

                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle(ex.getMessage().toString() + "second");
                    d.show();
                }
        }

        Toast.makeText(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this,"data Imported",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void displayListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();

        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_CAT,
                CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_CODE,
                CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_DESC,
                CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_UNIT,
                CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_QUANTITY
        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.category,
                R.id.code,
                R.id.description,
                R.id.unit,
                R.id.quantity
        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.country_info,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
                String countryCode =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Code"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.fetchCountriesByName(constraint.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my CountriesDbAdapter.class:
    public class CountriesDbAdapter {

```
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CAT = "Category";
    public static final String KEY_CODE = "Code";
    public static final String KEY_DESC = "Description";
    public static final String KEY_UNIT = "Unit";
    public static final String KEY_QUANTITY = "Quantity";

    private static final String TAG = "CountriesDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Count";
    private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Countsheet";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                    KEY_CAT + "," +
                    KEY_CODE + "," +
                    KEY_DESC + "," +
                    KEY_UNIT + "," +
                    KEY_QUANTITY + "," +
                    " UNIQUE (" + KEY_CODE +"));";

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public CountriesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public CountriesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    public long createCountry(String cat, String code, String desk,
                              String unit, String quantity) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_CAT, cat);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CODE, code);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DESC, desk);
        initialValues.put(KEY_UNIT, unit);
        initialValues.put(KEY_QUANTITY, quantity);

        return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteAllCountries() {

        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
        Log.w(TAG, inputText);
        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
            mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_CAT, KEY_CODE, KEY_DESC, KEY_UNIT,KEY_QUANTITY},
                    null, null, null, null, null,null);

        }
        else {
            mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_CAT, KEY_CODE, KEY_DESC, KEY_UNIT,KEY_QUANTITY},
                    KEY_DESC + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        }
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllCountries() {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_CAT, KEY_CODE, KEY_DESC, KEY_UNIT,KEY_QUANTITY},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public void insertSomeCountries() throws IOException {

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `dbHelper = new CountriesDbAdapter` as global

Comment: You have not initialized your reference to dbHelper

Comment: i Declared it already but still error see the edited code above

Comment: Make mDbHelper and mDb static and try.

Comment: I would suggest you to change your db helper class. Implement singleton pattern...

Comment: i make it staticand still error can you give me example in singleton pattern sorry im new to  this